# Ошибки "syntax error"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

Помогите разобраться с классом...

```
//заголовочный файл example.h  
class Example {  
public:  
        void GetName(int i);

private:  
    char x[5];  
};

//файл example.cpp  
#include <iostream>
#include "example.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {  
    Example Name;  
    Name.GetName(0);  
    return 0;  
}

void Example::GetName(int i) {  
    x = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4'};  
    cout << x[i];  
}
```

Ошибки:

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\MyProjects\Example\example.cpp(13) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'  
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\MyProjects\Example\example.cpp(13) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\MyProjects\Example\example.cpp(13) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  
> Error executing cl.exe.`
>
> `Example.exe - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x**[]** = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4'}; x - массив, работайте с ним как с массивом

```
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < sizeof(x) / sizeof(char) ; ++ii)
{ x[ii] = ii;  }
cout<<x[i]
```

В общем случае инициализацию нужно делать в конструкторе.

Comment: Да, но ведь мне нужно инициализировать массив char x[5]класса Example... Я просто спрыгнул с Питона ни Си, и очень сложно, если честно понять его классы...

Comment: Списки в питоне и массивы в С/С++ имеют разную семантику в некоторых случаях.

Цикл, который я написал, нужно вынести в конструктор. Т.о. при создании объекта класса его (объекта) массив X будет инициализирован.

Comment: А посему ошибочна конструкция в классе:

class Example {  
public:  
 void GetName(int i);  

private:  
 char x[5] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4'};  
};

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\myprojects\example\example.h(6) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\myprojects\example\example.h(6) : error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

Comment: Потому что инициализация атрибутов класса не может быть выполнена в месте их объявления (за исключением статических константных переменных).

Если хочется именно в месте объявления, то нужно использовать компилятор, поддерживающий стандарт С11

Comment: fogbit: уточню, за исключением *целочисленных* статических константных переменных

Comment: Спасибо! А я-то думаю... Можете привести на моем примере рабочий пример класса?

Comment: @dzhioev: http://ideone.com/iiOpN ?
@Xyanight: http://ideone.com/aolTN